# calculate a grid layout in python for scribus

Tags: python-2.7, layout, grid

I want to create a grid layout in [scribus](https://www.scribus.net) to create a photobook. The grid layout should take the image sizes in account and place the images accordingly. Like the pinterest layout / [masonry-layout](https://masonry.desandro.com/). For example as shown here (taken from the startpage of [masonry.desandro.com](https://masonry.desandro.com/))

[image: Masonry layout take from masonry.desandro.com]

Currently I try to find some information where I can start to dig in, so that I can build up such a programatically grid. But it's hard to find any good tutorial or explantion how to create such a calculation or I do not find the right keywords for my search.

In other words, I want to develop a script where I calculate x and y positions on a single page, which takes the image ratio in account and create a nice looking page. The image dimensions/ratio will be calculated with the information from [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow).

Any hints and tips where I get more information to dig into this topic is appreciated.

My current approach is not really usefull at the moment

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# run this script with 
# /Applications/Scribus.app/Contents/MacOS/Scribus -ns -py foobar.py

from scribus import *
from PIL import Image # Info: Scribus is build with python 2.7

# DIN A4 3508 x 2480 px = 29,7 x 21,0 cm; Ratio 3508/2480 = 1,41 = Portrait
# Ratio > 1 = Landscape 
# Ratio < 1 = Portrait 

# build a manuel grid for testing
# x,y,width, height 
pic1 = ( 15, 20, 270, 360 )
pic2 = ( 300, 20, 270, 360 )
pic3 = ( 15, 430, 270, 360 )
pic4 = ( 300, 430, 270, 360 )

layout = []
layout.append( pic1 )
layout.append( pic2 )
layout.append( pic3 )
layout.append( pic4 )

def doFrame( frame_layout ): 
    x,y,w,h = frame_layout
    createImage( x,y,w,h )

if newDocument(PAPER_A4, (10,10,10,10),PORTRAIT, 1, UNIT_POINTS, NOFACINGPAGES, FIRSTPAGERIGHT, 1):
    for frame in layout: 
        doFrame( frame )

    setRedraw(1)
    redrawAll()

else:
    result = messageBox ('Something is wrong',BUTTON_OK)
```

Comment: Did you get a success to complete the, because I also need like this.

Comment: @AliAbbas Not as described above. Complete randomly, did not work out, as I wanted the image-gallery on a DIN A4 size page, so I switched to a fix set of predefined layouts. Unfortunatly I struggeled to fill them correctly so that the outcome was as I desired. The next step would be to do some analysis on the images, so that I can select layouts that fit to the next set of images. On the way I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48689015/1933185) solved. Perhaps it helps you.