# list manipulation and recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a mansory-grid in a pdf-page. The grid is choosen randomly, so i do not know how much upright cells or cross cells I have to fill. In my list I have all images that I want to proceed, each marked if it is upright or cross. My approach is now:

1. get the grid for the page
2. iterate through the list and use the images which fit to the next grid-cell.
3. remove this image from the list
4. Proceed with the next cell.
5. if the grid on the page is filled proceed with the next page (Step 1)

To test my approach, I used the following script:

```
imageSet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
def fillLayout(images):
    print("Images in Stack", len(images))
    # Base condition to leave recursion
    if len(images) == 0: 
        print("finished")
        return 1

    idx = 0
    for image in images: 
        print(" index: ", idx, "item: ", image)
        del(images[idx]) # This marks the point, image is used on the cell layout and can be removed
        idx += 1
        if idx == 5: 
            print("break at idx: ", idx) 
            idx = 0
            break # This marks the point, grid is filled, proceed with the next page

    fillLayout(images)

fillLayout(imageSet)
```

I get the following output:

```
Images in Stack 16
 index:  0 item:  1
 index:  1 item:  3
 index:  2 item:  5
 index:  3 item:  7
 index:  4 item:  9
break at idx:  5
Images in Stack 11
 index:  0 item:  2
 index:  1 item:  6
 index:  2 item:  10
 index:  3 item:  12
 index:  4 item:  14
break at idx:  5
Images in Stack 6
 index:  0 item:  4
 index:  1 item:  11
 index:  2 item:  15
Images in Stack 3    <-- from now it does not proceed as expected
 index:  0 item:  8
 index:  1 item:  16
Images in Stack 1
 index:  0 item:  13
Images in Stack 0
finished
```

What I want is

```
...
Images in Stack 6
 index:  0 item:  4
 index:  1 item:  11
 index:  2 item:  15
 index:  0 item:  8
 index:  1 item:  16
break at idx:  5
Images in Stack 1
 index:  0 item:  13
finished
```

Any ideas what I am missing, or how to solve my problem.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that happens when you delete elements from a list you're iterating over.  One possible solution would be to iterate over a *copy* of the list: `for image in images[:]:`.

Comment: How do you decide which indexes to use?

Comment: ``for image in images[:]`` did not help, same result.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice In the further development, i analyse the value of the list and delete the item based on the value conditions. For simplicity i tested it as simple as possible

Comment: @jerik Please be more specific. How do you analyze the value? Which value do you analyze? What conditions tell you to delete the item from the list?

Comment: @jerik I suggest that you step away from the code for a little while. Pretend that you are explaining how to perform this task to another person. Give as much detail as possible. Just describe the steps in words and write it down. Once you have a clear idea how to describe this in English (or any other spoken language) then it will be easier to translate those words into code.

Comment: If it helps. I have a mansory-grid in a pdf-page. The grid is choosen randomly,  so i do not know how much upright or cross images I have to fill. In my list I have all images that I want to proceed, each marked if it is upright or cross. My approach is: get the grid for the page, iterate through the list, sort the images out which fit to the grid-cells (on this page) and proceed with the next page (and grid) with the same pattern.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I updated the description, so that it states my whole problem and how I try to approach it. If there are other approaches to resolve the problem, I am open for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear to me if you are intentionally trying to skip items on each pass or if that's accidental on your part as a side effect of your code. That is, it looks like a bug to me, but maybe it's a feature and not a bug.

If I wanted to remove 5 items from a list as a group and do something with them then recurse the function, I'd do this:

```
def fill_layout(images):
    out_items = []
    while len(out_items) <5 and images:
        out_items.append(images.pop(0))
    # do something to your 5 or less items in out_items
    if images:
        fill_layout(images)
```

Note, you don't need to recurse, you could just handle everything in the function. Further, you could just slice the list into 5 lengths and handle each one as you go. There is a lot of artificial complexity in your method and I don't know how much is actually needed from your example -- so I did this to keep the groups of 5, remove from list and recurse. There are probably simpler ways to do what you want.

Comment: the skipping is accidently. Seems that my approach to get closer to the solution, was not the 100% correct way...

Comment: Your solution seems to work. Its missing a condition to leave recursion. I have to test more. Thanks, to be proactive and not so negative like the others.

Comment: It will now exit recursion. `return 1` normally is an error. If you just want a function to end you can just do `return` or as I did above, just make it not recurse again and it'll exit naturally. If you are wanting a C style number return for some reason, then `return 0` would be no error, exit successful

Comment: I missed the ``if images:``. Now it works like desired. Thanks a lot